# Magento programmatically created attributes showing up in backend but not frontend

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7

I have a script that bulk creates attributes and sets in Magento. The attributes and their sets look fine, and the settings are correct. When these attributes are created, I use AMartinez's customimpertexport script to bulk import products. These products do have the attributes correctly filled in.

If I look at a product in the back-end, they are there, with the correct values. When I take a look at the front-end however, the values are not displayed. Also, the layered navigation does not work (probably because of forementioned bug).

This makes me think there is something going wrong with linking attributes to products.

Since I'm pretty new at Magento, I don't know very much of it yet, so any explanations on how or why would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your attributes' settings. "Use In Layered Navigation" and "Used in Product Listing" options should be enabled.

Also you should use default Magento import/export functionality. Just keep in mind that the script has a really strange and sillent way to handle exceptions in code formating and missing fields, only hard exceptions like missing SKU fields are displayed.
Here is a tutorial fromt he magento knowledge base
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should check of the attribute is visible on the frontend.